# Can we use patient as a verb?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Patienter is verb in French for to be patient. Why can't we have a verb too. It should be pronounced as in French - peshi-ent. Sentence: Could you please patient another week for your payment?

Comment: No. You must use *be patient*:  "Could you please be patient another week for your payment."

Comment: We have *wait*. You can certainly *try* to introduce and popularize a new meaning for *patient*, but that will take a very long time, so you're going to have to wait and have patience. (PS: English does not have *Les Immortels*; it's a language of the people, by the people, for the people. So you can't just petition *anyone* to adopt this new sense, you have to petition *everyone*.)

Comment: We have interesting verbs that communicate the French *patienter*: hang tight, hold on, stand by, wait...

Comment: *Your call is important to us...<musack...>...* In practice, *Veuillez patienter qq instants...* really means you are now being send to `/dev/null` limbo, just as does *Your call is important to us...*

Comment: " **pronounced as in French**": /pa.sjɑ̃/? Yeah, that's not gonna happen.

Comment: @MarkBeadles True! The French have always been able to talk better than they could spell, anyhow.

Comment: Total negation of patient as a verb. English evolves. I would use it with a [sic] to show I am innovating. I would show the context: Although normally patient William did show he had patiented enough and now the party was starting downstairs. BTW: Patiented is lit up by the spell-check.

Comment: Instant return. Above has total rejection of patient as a verb and goes on to show how to use it as adj. Fine. Luckily as we scroll down some person has taken care to show it  HAS been used in the past (by the Bard himself) AND could be used in context with the context shown: It was getting late for the party but he patiented for her wardrobe's sake. Idiosyncrasy is a trait tolerated in English writing.

Answer (score 7):

More or less any word can be verbed in English—that is, turned into a verb by [zero-derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)). That includes *patient*.

The trouble with *patient*, though, is that it is both an adjective and a noun, and the two mean quite different things (“able to accept or tolerate waiting, delays, etc.” vs. “a person who is ill or receiving medical attention”). Given enough context, that may not be a problem. The following would be easily understood, for example, as a humorous usage:

> Mary was placidly trying on what seemed like a never-ending array of clothes in the clothes store. Luckily, her husband was an extraordinarily patient man. He was so patient, in fact, that he patiently patiented for nearly three hours without complaining, until Mary had tried on and rejected every single item in the clothes store.

But without such a carefully set up context, the verb *patient* would be much more likely to be seen as derived from the noun than from the adjective.

Zero-derivation in English (and many other languages) is subject to an extremely complex network of semantic constraints. In English at least, verbs that are productively zero-derived from nouns that express persons are nearly always denominative factitives: a verb meaning ‘to turn X into Y’ or ‘to consider X to be Y’ or ‘to treat X as Y’. For a simple example, think of how *to knight* (derived from the noun *a knight*) means specifically to turn someone into a knight—it doesn’t mean, for example, to remove knights from something (in the way that *to dust*, derived from the noun *dust*, means ‘to remove dust from’) or anything else like that.

So the most likely meaning of *to patient* would be ‘to make/consider/turn X [into] a patient’, despite the fact that this is not something you’d often need a word for.

And in the context where the verb is most frequently found in French (in my experience, at least), it would be *highly* bizarre in English and would very likely not be understood as a verb at all:

> *Veuillez patienter quelques instants, s’il vous plaît. Nous allons donner suite à votre appel.*
>   Please *patient; your call will be transferred to the next available operator.

I daresay any native English speaker would look very oddly at their phone if their insurance company or Internet provider had an automated hold message that said that. They would most likely assume that it was supposed to say “Please *be* patient…”. But most likely, what they were expecting was “Please hold the line”.

Comment: *Hold the line* may be a British thing.  In America we most often hear, "Please remain on the line" or "Please continue to hold"  I can't say that I've ever heard "hold the line"-  but of course I'd know what it meant.

Comment: Nice answer, but would be better if the humorous example didn't rely on sexist cliché. In 2017, must we still take for granted a scenario that presents women as clothes- and shopping-obsessed creatures, and men as creatures who suffer due to those obsessions?

Comment: @verbose Who's taking anything for granted? Less exaggerated versions of this scenario do play out daily, in both directions. Feel free to switch the two characters around if you want; doesn't change the point.

Comment: I am so so pleased with how people have responded to the question and added value to it. It is not unoften [sic] that people seeing a "foreign" name dump on them, like they must be dumb about the language discussed her. So I am truly grateful for the answers. There is a bar on me for asking questions and I am trying to get it lifted by looking at all my questions and clarifying them. This on question having evoked so many responses cannot be considered as obscure.

Comment: I asked the question knowing full well patient does not exist as a verb in English but I do think it would be accepted in context and that context specifically explained. I would as suggested above use it with a [sic] to show I am innovating. I would show the context: Although normally patient William did show he had patiented enough and now the party was starting downstairs. BTW: Patiented is lit up by the spell-check.

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum to Janus' answer, *patient* used indeed to be a verb. It hasn't been since the middle of the seventeeth century.

> †**patient**, *verb*
>
> Etymology:  < **patient** *adj.* Compare Middle French, French *patienter* to be patient, show patience (1557 used reflexively, 1573 used intransitively), Italian *pazientare* (a1527, used intransitively).
>
> *Obs.*
>
> 1. *trans.* To make patient; (*refl.*) to calm or quiet oneself; to be patient.
>
> > 1594   Shakespeare *Titus Andronicus* i. i. 121   Patient your selfe Madam, and pardon me.
> >     1647   J. Trapp *Comm. Epist. & Rev.* (2 Thess. i. 4)   Faith patienteth the heart.
>
> 2. *intr.* To be patient, to show patience. *rare.*
>      App. only in imperative use.
>
> > 1593   G. Peele *Edward I* l. 44   Pacient your highnes, tis but mothers loue.
>
> [OED][edited]

It may be that a particular word can only bear a certain number of uses, and if one of those uses (say as a verb) can be subsumed into another (say with *be* and the adjectival use) then that tends to happen and the [verb] use becomes obsolete.

Comment: W_O_W it HAS been used in the past and the Bard himself used it. In that case I would use it in context with a [sic]. Thank you for the care you have taken to answer the question. Makes this a fantastic grammar site to participate [sic]. Thank you for patienting a bit longer. Patienter un peu plus.